# Replication using Ms Access 2007 distributor to MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007

Now I am doing the Payroll module, I want to synchronize the data from Microsoft Access 2007 into MS SQL Server 2008 (every day when the employee check in/out using finger print, the data store in the ms. access file, so at the end of the month, the admin of the finger print will sync the data from ms access to SQL Server 2008), because the system that I develop using SQL Server to store the employee profile include check in/out time. But now I want to synchronize it by myself and every day. So everyone could give me any suggestion of how to replicate the data from ms. access 2007 to SQL Server at the end of the work day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working from MS Access, the simplest thing to do is to link the SQL Server tables and run suitable queries.

[Import or link to SQL Server data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx)

Comment: Linking tables is fairly basic to the operation of MS Access. I have added a reference.

Comment: As the given link, It is link data from SQL Server to Access, Does the process of link from Ms. access is the same process from SQL Server to Ms. Acess?

Comment: Your questions implies you are working from MS Access. Where are you working from, SQL Server or MS Access?

Comment: I am trying to take data from MS Access to put in SQL Server.

Comment: You say "synchronizing from MS Access", but apparently you are synchronizing from SQL server. This may help http://www.tavislovell.com/post/How-to-create-a-Linked-Server-to-an-Access-DB-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Comment: Sorry for that, I got confuse about that word.

Comment: Follow this tutorial, In my SQL Server have no provider `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` , could you tell me how to add this in my SQL Server?

Comment: You can find everything you need with google: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/96676645-c7bc-44ab-9ca1-75918959a9cc/